# Even if one button is pressed, show another item. jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table with user data:

Again StackOverflow swears at "a little text, a lot of code", I have to write a lot of meaningless words, sorry.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fas.fa-edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.useredit, .fas.fa-times').show();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.fas.fa-edit, .userdata').hide();
    });

  $('.fas.fa-times').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.useredit, .fas.fa-times').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.fas.fa-edit, .userdata').show();
  });

  ////Here is a question
  if($('.fas.fa-times').is(':visible')){
    $('input.usereditbtn.btn.btn-success').hide();
  }else{
    $('input.usereditbtn.btn.btn-success').show();
  };
  ////Here is a question
});
```

```css
.useredit, .fas.fa-times, .usereditbtn{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table usertable">
   <thead>
   </thead>
   <form class="" action="{{ route('user_edit') }}" method="POST">
      <tbody>
         @csrf
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <td class="userdata">Name</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="name" placeholder="Write your name">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">E-Mail</th>
            <td class="userdata">email@email.com</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="email" placeholder="Write your Email">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
            <td class="userdata">555555555</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="phone" placeholder="
Enter your phone number">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input class="usereditbtn btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </form>
</table>
```

I have buttons, each for editing its own field. I need that if at least one button is enabled, then the `Save` button is visible, if all are closed, then the buttons are not visible.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a purpose for having multi buttons/icons while all of them will do the same action .. but anyways you can use `.each()` inside the edit `.click()` and times `.click()`  to loop through the buttons/icons

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.usereditbtn').closest('td').hide(0);
$('.fas.fa-edit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.usereditbtn').closest('td').show(0);
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('editing').find('.useredit, .fas.fa-times').show();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.fas.fa-edit, .userdata').hide();
});
$('.fas.fa-times').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('editing').find('.useredit, .fas.fa-times').hide();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.fas.fa-edit, .userdata').show();
  if(!$('tr.editing').length){
    $('.usereditbtn').closest('td').hide(0);
  }
});

////Here is a question
if($('.fas.fa-times').is(':visible')){
  $('input.usereditbtn.btn.btn-success').hide();
}else{
  $('input.usereditbtn.btn.btn-success').show();
};
////Here is a question
});
```

```css
.useredit, .fas.fa-times{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table usertable">
   <thead>
   </thead>
   <form class="" action="{{ route('user_edit') }}" method="POST">
      <tbody>
         @csrf
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <td class="userdata">Name</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="name" placeholder="Write your name">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">E-Mail</th>
            <td class="userdata">email@email.com</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="email" placeholder="Write your Email">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
            <td class="userdata">555555555</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="phone" placeholder="
Enter your phone number">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input class="usereditbtn btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Each button activates only its own field. I used to have one button that activated all fields, but what's the point. Look at any site or service. There is a separate edit button for name, email, etc. And the point was in displaying the `Save` button, you have it always visible, but I only need it when at least one of the edit fields is active.

Comment: @Hi_TecH to have edit icon to edit its own field its Ok and to have one icon to edit all fields also Ok.. but to make any individual icon edit all fields its not Ok .. So you got the point of my code then .. you can add a general icon to edit all fields and you can use `.each(.....` in my code inside the general icon `.click(`

Comment: In my case, each button edits its own field. Have you run Snippet?
I have already done the option when one button activates all fields, it's not difficult, but I still decided to make a separate button for each field.

Comment: @Hi_TecH Ok I got it .. I updated my answer with disabled save button .. add `disabled` in save input html tag , then use `.prop('disabled' , true/false)` to disabled/enabled the button

Comment: You have the same bug as mine. If for example you open 2 fields, and then close one, the button will become inactive. This is exactly what I need to solve.

Comment: @Hi_TecH mm So your question should start from here man .. Ok I'll work on that

Comment: @Hi_TecH answer updated .. by `add/removeClass('editing')` to the `tr` and check for `tr.editing` length

Comment: My pleasure @Hi_TecH ... have a nice day :-)

Comment: You too!) One clarification, how to do the same, only to make the button disappear. Tried replacing everything with hide/show doesn't work)

Comment: @Hi_TecH simple wait a second

Comment: @Hi_TecH for some reason -I think bootstrap styling- can't hide the button on load .. so I decided to hide/show the button `td` instead .. if you still need to hide/show the button itself you can use `$('.usereditbtn').fadeOut(100)` to hide the button on load instead of `$('.usereditbtn').closest('td').hide(0);` then use `$('.usereditbtn').hide()`and `$('.usereditbtn').show()`

Comment: @Hi_TecH Also I think if you add you style sheet after bootstrap css with `.usereditbtn{display : none}` it may work

Comment: @Hi_TecH to be honest to add `id` and use `#save{display:none;}` as DCR said its a very good solution to hide the button on page load then you can use `$('.usereditbtn').hide();`and `$('.usereditbtn').show();` and everything will work as expected .. Good Luck :-)

Comment: I did as you said in the previous comment and it works!) Thanks again!
Yes, DCR's option is also good. It's a pity that 2 answers cannot be accepted).

Answer (score 1):

you need to display:block in your top function and display:none in your bottom function.  Check code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fas.fa-edit').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();


$(this).closest('tr').find('.useredit, .fas.fa-times').show();
$(this).closest('tr').find('.fas.fa-edit, .userdata').hide();

var cnt = 0;
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times')
for (let i = 0; i < check.length;i++){
    if(check[i].style.display != '' && check[i].style.display != 'none')cnt++
}
var save = document.getElementById('save')
if(cnt != 0){
   
   save.className = "usereditbtn btn btn-success"
   save.style.display='block'
}





});
$('.fas.fa-times').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$(this).closest('tr').find('.useredit, .fas.fa-times').hide();
$(this).closest('tr').find('.fas.fa-edit, .userdata').show();

var cnt = 0;
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('useredit')
for (let i = 0; i < check.length;i++){
    if(check[i].style.display != '' && check[i].style.display != 'none')cnt++
}
var save = document.getElementById('save')
if(cnt == 0){ 

   save.className = ""
   save.style.display='none'
   }




});


});
```

```css
.useredit, .fas.fa-times, #save {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table usertable">
   <thead>
   </thead>
   <form class="" action="{{ route('user_edit') }}" method="POST">
      <tbody>
         @csrf
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <td class="userdata">Name</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="name" placeholder="Write your name">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">E-Mail</th>
            <td class="userdata">email@email.com</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="email" placeholder="Write your Email">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
            <td class="userdata">555555555</td>
            <td class="useredit"><input name="phone" placeholder="
Enter your phone number">
            <td>
            <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input id='save'  type="submit" value="Save"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only question is, how correct is it to use native JS and jQuery in the same code?

Comment: jquery is written for the most part with native js.  no problem to mix them together.  Please accept answer if it works for you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops in my mind is that you can assign a `class` to each of those edit `buttons` once they are clicked.

More precisely, toggle that class (add it when the button is clicked, then remove it when the button is clicked again, you can use toggleClass method in jQuery).

This way, you can use jQuery's `hasClass` method which returs a boolean if a certain element has a certain class in that moment.

So, all you have to do is grab all of the edit buttons, and run a `for` loop thorugh them (on every click of one of those buttons, of course), if at least one of them has that extra `class` you added (meaning that one or more edit buttons are activated in that moment), then you can hide the `Save` button.

Vice versa, if none of those buttons have that extra class, that means non of them is currently active, and then you can show the Save button again.

Hope I wasnt too confusing here !

Of couse, there are dozens of ways you can do this task, this just happened to pop first in my mind.